# Is my reasoning about Borel Lebesgue theorem correct?

Tags: real-analysis

I was thinking alone about the Borel Lebesgue theorem in R: "Any open cover of a compact set contains a finite open sub cover"

My first thought was: "Why doesn't it work for a closed cover?" And my insight was this:
intervals within a closed cover doesn't need to "overlap" in both endpoints, so you might end up in a situation where you cannot afford removing any of the infinite number of sets in the cover. For instance:

$I = [a,b]$

$U_k = [a, b-\frac{1}{k}]$

Then the cover $\cup^{k=1}_{\infty} U_k$ is a cover because the series $X_n = b - \frac{1}{n}$ converges to $b \in I$, because I is closed. So removing any of the $U_k$ will make some element out.

The thing with open intervals is that they need to overlap so you can cover any specific interval with more than one open interval.

Is that insight correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$U_k$'s do not cover $[a,b]$ since $b$ is not in any of them.

$[a,b]$ is the union of all singleton sets $\{\{x\}: a \leq x \leq b\}$ and this gives  a closed cover with no finite subcover.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, indeed b is not covered by the cover. I was thinking always about intervals, but yes, singletons sets are closed. Thanks.